# Возведение в степень длинного числа и сумма всех чисел от и до

Tags: c, массивы

Я почти всё написал, вот только мне не хватает ума/сил/времени ,чтобы решить два вопроса : Возвести в степень длинное число и просуммировать числа от и до(от и до -это числа , задающиеся пользователем )
вот мой код(спасите):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
const int N = 1000;

int complong(int* a, int* b) {
    int i = 0;

    if (a[0] < b[0]) return -1;

    if (a[0] > b[0]) return 1;

    for (i = a[0]; i > 0; i--) {
        if (a[i] < b[i]) return -1;

        if (a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

void readlong(int* a) {
    int i = 0, k = 0;
    char s[N + 1];
    gets_s(s, N + 1);
    a[0] = strlen(s);

    for (i = 0; i < a[0]; i++) {
        a[a[0] - i] = s[i] - '0';
    }
}

void writelong(int* a) {
    int i = 0;

    for (i = a[0]; i >= 1; i--)
        printf("%d", a[i]);
}

void main(void) {
    int a[N + 5] = { 0 };
    int b[N + 5] = { 0 };
    int y[N + 1] = { 0 };
    int m = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int i = 0;
    char p = 0, g = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int cr = 0;
    int u = 0;
    int l = 0;
    int q = 0;
    printf("Enter the opearation");
    scanf_s("%c", &p);
    scanf_s("%*c", &p);
    fflush(stdin);

    switch (p) {
        case'!': {
            printf("Enter the number to factorize ");
            scanf_s("%d", &l);
            int d = 1000000;
            int A[N] = { 1 };
            int  len = 1, r, s;

            for (k = 2; k <= l; k++) {
                i = 0; //
                r = 0; //

                while (i < len
                        || r > 0) {
                    s = A[i] * k + r;
                    A[i] = s % d;
                    r = s / d;
                    i++;
                }

                len = i;
            }

            for (i = len - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if (i == len - 1) printf("%d", A[i]);
                else printf("%.6d", A[i]);

            break;
        }

        case'-': {
            printf("Enter the first number ");
            readlong(a);
            printf("\nEnter the second number ");
            readlong(b);

            if (complong(a, b) < 0) {
                printf("-");
                c = 0;

                for (i = 1; i <= b[0]; i++) {
                    c = c + b[i] - a[i] + 10;
                    b[i] = c % 10;

                    if (c < 10) {
                        c = -1;
                    } else {
                        c = 0;
                    }
                }

                while ((b[b[0]] == 0 && b[0] > 1)) b[0] = b[0] - 1;

                writelong(b);
                break;
            } else {
                c = 0;

                for (i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++) {
                    c = c + a[i] - b[i] + 10;
                    a[i] = c % 10;

                    if (c < 10) {
                        c = -1;
                    } else {
                        c = 0;
                    }
                }

                while ((a[a[0]] == 0 && a[0] > 1)) a[0] = a[0] - 1;

                writelong(a);
            }

            break;
        }

        case'+': {
            printf("Enter the first number ");
            readlong(a);
            printf("\nEnter the second number ");
            readlong(b);

            if (a[0] > b[0]) {
                m = a[0];
            } else {
                m = b[0];
            }

            c = 0;

            for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
                c = c + a[i] + b[i];
                a[i] = c % 10;
                c = c / 10;
            }

            if (c > 0) {
                m = m + 1;
                a[m] = c;
            }

            a[0] = m;
            writelong(a);
            break;
        }

        case'*': {
            printf("Enter the first number ");
            readlong(a);
            printf("\nEnter the second number ");
            readlong(b);
            cr = 0;

            for (i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++) {
                for (j = 1; j <= b[0]; j++) {
                    cr = a[i] * b[j];
                    k = i + j - 1;

                    while (cr > 0) {
                        cr = cr + y[k];
                        y[k] = cr % 10;
                        cr = cr / 10;

                        if (k > y[0]) y[0] = k;

                        k = k + 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            writelong(y);
            break;
        }

        case'^': { //возведение в степень
            int n = 0;
            printf("Enter the first number ");
            readlong(a);
            printf("\nEnter the stepen ");
            scanf_s("%d", &n);
            cr = 0;

            for (i = 1; i <= a[0]; i++) {
                for (j = 1; j <= a[0]; j++) {
                    cr = a[i] * a[j];
                    k = i + j - 1;

                    while (cr > 0) {
                        cr = cr + y[k];
                        y[k] = cr % 10;
                        cr = cr / 10;

                        if (k > y[0]) y[0] = k;

                        k = k + 1;

                        for (q = 1; q < N - 1; q++) {
                            m = y[q];
                            y[q] = a[q];
                            a[q] = m;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            writelong(a);
            break;
        }

        default:
            printf("Incorrect operation");
            break;
    }

    _getch();
}
```

Вот честно не понимаю , как как возвести в степень эти циферки , и как просуммировать числа от и до

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не вдаюсь в ваш код. Важно, что у вас есть умножение и сложение. Теперь вам нужно еще деление пополам (оно реализуется несложно). Как только у вас будет это деление пополам, ваша задача решится просто.

Задача просуммировать все числа от `a` до `b` включительно сводится к вычислению `(b-a+1)*(b+a)/2`, а возведения в степень - [быстрым возведением в степень](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/binary_pow). Оно основано на том, что для любого числа `a` и чётного числа `n` выполнимо очевидное тождество

```
a^n = (a^{n/2})^2 = a^{n/2} * a^{n/2}
```

Для чётного `n` всего одна операцию умножения сводит задачу к вдвое меньшей степени.

Если степень нечётна, то переходим к степени `n-1`, которая будет чётной:

```
a^n = a^{n-1} * a
```

Получается алгоритм, работающий за `O(log n)` умножений. Подробнее см. по ссылке.

По-другому - напрямую суммировать и множить большие числа - вы замучитесь. Если еще возведение в 20-значную степень вам вряд ли зададут, то суммировать все числа от одного 30-значного числа до другого - запросто. А деление пополам, как видите, нужно в обоих алгоритмах.